# Directus images disappear after a while

Tags: image, heroku, directus

I created a Next.js project that is deployed on Vercel and uses a MySQL database. I then deployed a Directus instance on Heroku that is tied to that same database. In my Next.js project I want to fetch and render images that I uploaded to Directus. At first this works, but after a while all the images disappear in the Directus media library. The folders and references to the images are still there, but I don't see the pictures anymore, I get to see a JPG logo instead. When I try to fetch the images I get a 502 "Bad Gateway" error. I don't know what causes the images to disappear and how to fix this. [image]

Comment: You'll have to configure it to save images somewhere persistent, like Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage. I'm not familiar with that product, or how it should be configured. But see [the very many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+uploads+disappear) [exiting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+images+disappear) about this.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Directus stores uploaded files locally on disk.

All Heroku applications run in a collection of lightweight Linux containers called dynos. Be aware that Heroku dyno's filesystem is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

It means if your Heroku app doesn't receive any traffic for **30 minutes** or is being deployed, the VM it lives on is destroyed, and its filesystem goes along with it. So, this filesystem should not be used for any permanent storage (Directus storage in your case).

You can configure Directus to use *S3*, *Google Cloud Storage*, *Azure*, or *Cloudinary*.

For more details check the [File Storage](https://docs.directus.io/self-hosted/config-options.html#file-storage) Directus docs.